# Change behaviour of fn + f1-12 on Toshiba

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro C70-B-135 and Ubuntu 14.04. This laptop came with Windows 7, so it's dual boot.

My issue is that in windows 7, f1-12 keys were in default mode (I mean, I didn't have to press the fn key in order to active the function). Now, with Ubuntu, this feature is swaped, so I have to press this annoying key every time I want to change brightness or volume.

Every key works fine, it's only that the function is swaped. If there's any way I can change that using the terminal, I will be very grateful. If it isn't possible, I'll try everything I can

Notice that I checked all the possibilities at the right, and none of then solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following installed:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi-support fnfxd toshset
```

You may need to reboot. I believe this is a BIOS setting for toshiba laptops so check the BIOS settings to make sure this is properly set (in case Windows 7 may also have a setting for this as well).

Comment: I checked the BIOS, and found the setting for the fn keys, but I changed it and still doesn't work. I also tried to install that package, but doesn't work